# Issues with nmcli on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: lts, nmcli

I am trying to make it work but run into the following :

> remstr@DESKTOP-V1MD90G:~/ng$ nmcli nm Error: Object 'nm' is unknown,
> try 'nmcli help'.
>
> remstr@DESKTOP-V1MD90G:~/ng$ nmcli -v nmcli tool, version 1.2.6
>
> remstr@DESKTOP-V1MD90G:~/ng$ nmcli dev wifi-sec
>
> (process:3353): nmcli-CRITICAL **: Error: Could not create NMClient
> object: Could not connect: No such file or directory.
>
> remstr@DESKTOP-V1MD90G:~/ng$ sudo stop network-manager
> stop: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket >
> /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused

Comment: The `nm` object has been replaced by a `general` object I think - see [Differences in nmcli v0.9.8 vs. v0.9.10](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/nmcli). I don't know the equivalent for the `dev wifi-sec` command.

Comment: is it possible to install nmcli v0.9.8? I have tried the following :  remstr@DESKTOP-V1MD90G:~/ng$ sudo apt-get install network-manager=0.9.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '0.9.8' for 'network-manager' was not found

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: to install the nmcli version that was compatible with the command nmcli dev wifi-sec